# Split a string based on a condition

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to split a spreadsheet cell reference (eg, `A10`, `AB100`, `ABC5`) to two string parts: column reference and row reference.

`A10` => `A` and `10`
`AB100` => `AB` and `100` ...

Does anyone know how to do this by string functions?

Comment: You can't split in this case, use regular expression to extract those tokens instead.

Comment: `/(\D+)(\d+)/` - http://www.regular-expressions.info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easiest to do with a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) (regex). For example:

```
var ref = "AA100";
var matches = ref.match(/^([a-zA-Z]+)([1-9][0-9]*)$/);
if (matches) {
    var column = matches[1];
    var row = Number(matches[2]);
    console.log(column); // "AA"
    console.log(row); // 100
} else {
    throw new Error('invalid ref "' + ref + '"');
}
```

The important part here is the regex literal, `/^([a-zA-Z]+)([1-9][0-9]*)$/`. I'll walk you through it.

- `^` anchors the regex to the start of the string. Otherwise you might match something like "123ABC456".
- `[a-zA-Z]+` matches one or more character from a-z or A-Z.
- `[1-9][0-9]*` matches exactly one character from 1-9, and then zero or more characters from 0-9. This makes sure that the number you are matching never starts with zero (i.e. "A001" is not allowed).
- `$` anchors the regex to the end of the string, so that you don't match something like "ABC123DEF".
- The parentheses around `([a-zA-Z]+)` and `([1-9][0-9]*)` "capture" the strings inside them, so that we can later find them using `matches[1]` and `matches[2]`.

This example is strict about only matching valid cell references. If you trust the data you receive to always be valid then you can get away with a less strict regex, but it is good practice to always validate your data anyway in case your data source changes or you use the code somewhere else.

It is also up to you to decide what you want to do if you receive invalid data. In this example I make the script throw an error, but there might be better choices in your situation (e.g. prompt the user to enter another value).

Answer (score 1):

```js
var res = "AA123";

//Method 1
var arr = res.match(/[a-z]+|[^a-z]+/gi);
document.write(arr[0] + "<br>" + arr[1]);

//Method 2 (as deceze suggested)
var arr = res.match(/([^\d]+)(\d+)/);
document.write("<br>" + arr[1] + "<br>" + arr[2]);

//Note here [^\d] is the same as \D
```